# How to get all contact names using a phone number?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I`m trying to get all the contact names associated with a given phone number on android.

```
public void getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
     Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
      ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
            System.out.println("ID : " + contactId + " Name : " + contactName);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

But I`m getting the duplicate values

```
10-02 16:47:06.585  23359-23359/? I/System.out﹕ ID : 3480 Name : Issac
10-02 16:47:06.585  23359-23359/? I/System.out﹕ ID : 3480 Name : Issac
10-02 16:47:06.585  23359-23359/? I/System.out﹕ ID : 3401 Name : Ann
10-02 16:47:06.585  23359-23359/? I/System.out﹕ ID : 2819 Name : Sam
10-02 16:47:06.585  23359-23359/? I/System.out﹕ ID : 3480 Name : Issac
10-02 16:47:06.585  23359-23359/? I/System.out﹕ ID : 3480 Name : Issac
10-02 16:47:06.585  23359-23359/? I/System.out﹕ ID : 2819 Name : Sam
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? How do i get all the contact names by passing a phone number?

Comment: add `TYPE` and `NUMBER` to your projection and use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor`

Comment: @pskink  `Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.TYPE, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER}, null, null, null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);` Is this correct? I`m getting the same result

Comment: I dont see the logcat

Comment: `10-02 17:43:02.169    2912-2912/? I/System.out﹕ >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@428556a0
10-02 17:43:02.169    2912-2912/? I/System.out﹕ 0 { display_name=Issac  _id=3480  type=3 number=9545856193  }
.
.
.
10-02 17:43:02.179    2912-2912/? I/System.out﹕ 6 { display_name=Sam  _id=2819  type=0 number=9125689193 }` @pskink

Comment: and what's do you have duplicates?

Comment: @pskink yes,i got the same result

Comment: if you dont want to post your logcat that's ok

Answer (score 0):

I really don`t know why the cursor returning same values multiple times.To get the unique values,I stored the ids in arraylist which holds only unique values.Then by looping contact ids i can get the contact details

```
public void getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, 
    new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID},null, null, null);
    List<String> listIds = new ArrayList<String>(); //Arraylist to hold the unique ids
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
            if(!listIds.contains(contactId))
                listIds.add(contactId); //adding unique id to arraylist
        }
        //pass unique ids to get contact names
        for (int i = 0; i < listIds.size(); i++) {
            String newId = listIds.get(i);
            Cursor cursorDetails = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{newId}, null);
            if (cursorDetails != null) {
                if (cursorDetails.moveToFirst()) {
                    String contactName = cursorDetails.getString(cursorDetails.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    System.out.println("ID : " + newId + " Name : " + contactName + " Number : " + phoneNumber);
                }
                cursorDetails.close();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Logcat output:

```
10-03 12:24:08.161 6306-6306/? I/System.out: ID : 3480 Name : Issac 
10-03 12:24:08.161 6306-6306/? I/System.out: ID : 3401 Name : Ann
10-03 12:24:08.171 6306-6306/? I/System.out: ID : 2819 Name : Sam
```